# Text in Cocos3d

Tags: ios, cocos3d

I am developing an iPhone application that uses Cocos3d to draw shapes and images. Now I want to draw some text. Can anyone please guide me on how to draw text using Cocos3d?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to embed text in the 3D scene (like add a sign on a wall within the 3D scene), you can use `CC3BitmapLabelNode`. The `CC3DemoMashUp` app includes an example of how to do this, in the `addBitmapLabel` method of `CC3DemoMashUpScene`. The example actually does more than you need, because it uses a specialized subclass of `CC3BitmapLabelNode` that wraps the text around a cylinder. But it will give you the idea of how to use `CC3BitmapLabelNode`.

If you want to add text as a 2D overlay as part of the user interface (like a button, menu, or message to the user), use the standard Cocos2D components for that. You can add these 2D components to your customized `CC3Layer`. See the `CC3DemoMashUpLayer` for an example of how to do this.

Comment: Thank you Bill! Worked perfectly!